# Delphi TListBox iOS making new itemstyle/behavior

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I need to show custom data. For **example** I need to show a contact list with name, description, photo. And ideally I would also like to show custom data there, e.g. a button to launch telephone call. The default styles do not quite do what I want, but fairly close.

Thus, as far as I can tell, TListBox could be a decent control for this if I could create custom styles? Is that possible? (Anotther problem of course is setting the values of the custom data controls.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a good look at the FMX CustomListBox example AFAIK even the example alone already seems to have exactly what you need, already set in place.

It took me about 10 minutes to produce this result straight out of the CustomListBox example with your description:

[image]

One thing that the included FMX example demonstrates perfectly is how easy it is to add any FMX control to the ListBox via the [TStyleBook](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Controls.TStyleBook) Layouts such as buttons, images etc... basically any visual control upon which you then implement the [HitTest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.HitTest), again, all very detailed in the FMX Delphi example.

Comment: Upvoted. Will return tomorrow when I have tried. If there is an example anywhere close to what you describe, you definitely got the bounty! :)

Comment: @peter-vonca In Fire Monkey Mobile there is no Edit Custom Style or Edit Default Style by right clicking on components, since the question was on `ios` would you mind if you explain it more, how you did that?

Comment: @RezaRahmati, While there is no button to edit Custom Style, one can edit it just the same, you will find all required info in the following link : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles