# What control should I use to create this UI in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-xe, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am developing an application for mobile (android and ios) by Delphi xe5.

I am willing to create this UI:

[image]

I tried `TListBox` but image on left and right cant be set.

I tried `TListView` but same problem as `TListBox`

I tried `TGrid` with `custom column`, The problem of texts and images is solved but I can't create headers of each rows (it hasn't something like colspan)

What I need is to create a custom control and repeat it.

What is the best solution?

Any solution or guide line will be appreciated.

### Solution

Thanks @Mike Sutton for answer, this is the result
[image]

Comment: This could be done with styles

Comment: @SirRufo Edit Style menu is not available on Firemonkey Mobile Forms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220765/delphi-tlistbox-ios-making-new-itemstyle-behavior

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE5_Update/FireMonkeyMobile/Delphi/ListView/

Comment: Styles most certainly **can** be edited for Firemonkey Mobile. There's even a sample of doing so with a TListView. See the Samples\FireMonkeyMobile\Delphi\Listview folder - make sure to see the readme.txt in that folder, particularly the last paragraph about needing to build and install the packages before opening the project itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style here is so different from a standard TListBoxItem style that is probably makes sense to start from scratch, in which case the issues with accessing the default styles become immaterial.

- Add a TStyleBook to your form.
- Set the StyleBook property of the form to point to it.
- Double click the icon to open the editor.
- Drag a TLayout to the structure panel and drop it on the only item which will be there.
- Set the StyleName property of the TLayout (e.g. ScoreListBoxItemStyle).
- Drag/drop other components to build up the layout you want (remember TLayouts for 'hidden' positioning).
- Set the StyleName property of any components you want reference from your code.
- Subclass TLIstBoxItem to TScoreListBoxItem (if using the StyleName suggested above).
- Add properties for your text, images etc.
- In the setter methods for each of these, cache the data and call a method such as:

`procedure SetFlag1;
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  O := FindStyleResource('flag1');  //StyleName of the item
  if O is TImage then 
    TImage(O).Bitmap.Assign(FFlag1);
end;`

- Override the ApplyStyle method and call *all* of your methods that set the data in the style.
- Now create your items in code:

`Item := TScoreListBoxItem.Create(Self);
ListBox1.AddObject(Item);
Item.Flag1.LoadFromReource ...
...`

Comment: Thanks, for detailed answer, do I need to set StyleName of Item to what I have created in my style book?

Comment: Styling and setting the correct position is really pain in the neck

Comment: StyleName is how FMX finds the correct style element. If you set the style name as per my example above it will get picked up automatically by FMX for the TScoreListBoxItem. Otherwise you'll need to set the StyleLookup to reference it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that I don't have time to test:

Create a descendant of a `TListBoxItem` and in that add you two images as normal TImages. I'm pretty sure that a `TListBoxItem` can parent an object. You'll have to place the images on the  listbox item where you want them. Then whenever you add an item to the listbox item just pass in your own descendant.

(If this doesn't work someone let me know and I'll delete this.)

Comment: Indeed, this will work, although a solution with styles would be neater.